# Sharepoint ACS WAAD

Tags: azure, sharepoint, acs

I am trying to get this scenario working, I have a Sharepoint front end and a service webapi backend, I have my web APi protected using WAAD. And because sharepoint does not support JWT I had to use ACS to be its idp as ACS gives SAML1.1.

Now my question is how can I get a JWT token to access my backend from Sharepoint which has access to the SAML1.1 token which it got when user initially authenticated himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is working fine. 
Steps
1) User redirected to ACS when logs into sharepoint configured with ACS as the provider.
2) Chooses AAD as the IDP
3) logs into AAD, gets redirected back to ACS and gets the SAML 1.1 token.
4) Now when I redirect my browser from inside sharepoint to AAD requesting a token for the user requesting an Authorization code I get it from AAD.

Here the bit I think why it does work is my browser has the cookies that have fedAuth cookies which AAD had issued in the first place.  Can someone confirm that it is actually the case. For now I think it is working this way for me.